# About Python run in Linux web server

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am trying to run my python programme in the Linux server but there have some problem. I am using openCV to build a fall-detection and it can run in my local computer, but when I put the python into the linux server it can't run it... Here is my code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs, sys , cgi
import cv2
import time
import os

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
# Start html
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')


# Video clip
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Testvideo.mkv')
# Webcam camera
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print("Start Fall detection")
#time.sleep(2)

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
f = 0
j = 0

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert each frame to gray scale and subtract the background
    try:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(gray)

        # Find contours
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
            fgmask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        if contours:

            # List to hold all areas
            areas = []

            for contour in contours:
                ar = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                areas.append(ar)

            max_area = max(areas, default=0)

            max_area_index = areas.index(max_area)

            cnt = contours[max_area_index]

            M = cv2.moments(cnt)

            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

            cv2.drawContours(fgmask, [cnt], 0, (255, 255, 255), 3, maxLevel=0)

            if h < w:
                j += 1

            if j > 25:
                print(f"FALL !! ==> {f+1}")
                f += 1
                if f ==5:
                    print("Danger!!!")
                    #os.system("python send.py")
                    #os.system("python sms.py")
                #cv2.putText(fgmask, 'FALL Detect', (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            if h > w:
                j = 0
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cv2.imshow('video', frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
                break

    except Exception as e:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And it only will display
Start Fall detection

in the server, Please give me some help

Comment: is the Python version in the server the same as the version in your device ?

Comment: needs more debugging details, specifically the errors you get. please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: If you want to create an html page then imshow is not the way how to pass the image to your web browser. Perhaps you want to dig deeper into developing HTML services with python, first?

Comment: It happened to me right now when I attempting to do roi by using right linux. I can merely troubleshooting for you. There are so many ways to do . But it is easier for me to do this. Remove try/except. And add this  'umat'.    contours= cv2.findContours(gmask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0].